# Integration of DiracDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I just came across the following curiosity, and I'm not sure whether it's a bug or just me missing something. Here's a minimal example: I defined the following "function"

```
In[1]:= S[x_, y_, z_] := DiracDelta[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1];
```

which is supposed to parametrize the surface of a unit sphere.  However, when I integrate over the entire space ($x,y,z \in [-2,2]$ should do) I get $2\pi$ as a result

```
In[2]:= Integrate[S[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]

Out[2]:= 2 Pi
```

Shouldn't this be rather $4\pi$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Mathematica is correct here:

$$\int_{-2}^2 \delta(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)~ dx dy dz
= \int_0^\infty dr \int_0^\pi d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi ~r^2\sin\theta~ \delta(r^2-1)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty d(r^2) \int_0^\pi d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi ~r\sin\theta~ \delta(r^2-1) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi ~ \sin\theta= 2\pi$$

Comment: Hmpf... you beat me to it ;) +1

Comment: I think it would be nice to replace the integration region in the first integral by `R^3` though.

Comment: Damn, you are absolutely right! In order to get 4*Pi I would have to replace the argument of the delta"function" by (Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]-1). Cheers!

Comment: Unexpected but true. Here's a Generalisation: In[175]:= Integrate[
 DiracDelta[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^a - 1], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Out[175]= (2*Pi)/Abs[a]